# searching for a string value pair in json object using mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a json object in my database table field like following :

`[{"user_id":"xyz","viewed":"false","answered":"false","denied":"false"}]`.
the other fields are id, q_id and stuff.

I want to search for the user xyz in the table!how can i do that using mysql?

Comment: `search for the user` could you please elaborate a bit on it ?

Comment: i want to search for xyz in the above object! How can i accomplish that?

Comment: still did not get.. so your input value will be xyz and you want to see if its there in the object which is stored in database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your answers. But i just used a like query and it worked

```
SELECT viewers from tablename where viewers like '%\"user_id\":\"xyz\"%' && qid= 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

> **JSON Parsing in MySQL Using Common_schema**

Try following query using [common schema](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/)

```
select * from tablename where common_schema.extract_json_value(tablename.columnName,'/user_id') = 'xyz';
```

**Reference:** http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/04/08/json-parsing-in-mysql-using-common-schema/

Answer (score 1):

If the object pattern is same across then you can use the `substring_index` function to parse the data, below is the example of finding the user_id from this pattern

```
mysql> select replace(substring_index(substring_index('[{"user_id":"xyz","viewed":"false","answered":"false","denied":"false"}]','"user_id":',-1),',',1),'"','') as user_id;
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
| xyz     |
+---------+
```

Now if you want to select all the rows having `user_id = xyz` you can use the above as

```
select * from table_name 
where replace(substring_index(substring_index('[{"user_id":"xyz","viewed":"false","answered":"false","denied":"false"}]','"user_id":',-1),',',1),'"','') = 'xyz';
```

Comment: Thanks for this, helped reduce query times by 400ms on a ~10k row table! much more efficient than using LIKE as the (self answered) "Correct" answer does!

Comment: It could reduce the time, however thats not an efficient way of storing the user_id like this as a flat JSON, rather the application level should parse the user_id before storing into the DB and then by using the column index it could be far far bettter.

Comment: 100% agree, but working with a database tied into a black box system here, unfortunately, these things have to be done!

Answer (score 0):

In mysql there is a functionality for dba called [common schema](https://code.google.com/p/common-schema/). It has json functionality.
Or
use find_in_set() function to find coma seperated values in json.

Comment: SELECT IF(FIND_IN_SET('"viewed":"false"','[{"user_id":"xyz","viewed":"false","answered":"false","denied":"false"}]'),1,0) AS z