# updating a json object in a mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to update an json object in my database table field using php.

```
[{"user_id":"xyz","viewed":"false","answered":"false","denied":"false"}]
```

i want to set viewed as true!

how can i go about it?

Comment: Looks pretty much same issue hun http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120859/searching-for-a-string-value-pair-in-json-object-using-mysql

Comment: that was for a search(select)query. Now i want to do update on the same object and i want to set the viewed as true!

Comment: $json=[{"user_id":"xyz","viewed":"false","answered":"false","denied":"false"}];

then try $json->viewed ="true";

Comment: shall i json_decode it first?

Comment: what you are gettin now?

Comment: Attempt to assign property of non-object

Comment: try json_decode before it,then it will be converted into object,after that you can json_encode it if needed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65597/discussion-between-vaisakh-pc-and-user3851607).

Comment: of course, fetch it first, then decode, change the following field, then to reapply changes by using an update statements. thats about it